# __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ 18 23 CoreFoundation crash

Tags: ios, multithreading, crash

I am getting following crash. Can anyone tell me the reason for this crash?

```
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18 23  CoreFoundation  crash
```

I`m not using threads.
The NSZombieEnabled and instruments did not clarify the reason of the crash at all.
Please, help me.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b0805be objc_msgSend + 30
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3332130c CFRelease + 96
2   CoreFoundation                  0x333fc430 __CFBasicHashDrain + 256
3   CoreFoundation                  0x333213ce CFRelease + 290
4   CoreFoundation                  0x333fc430 __CFBasicHashDrain + 256
5   CoreFoundation                  0x333213ce CFRelease + 290
6   ImageIO                         0x34013008 _CGImagePlusFinalize + 48
7   CoreFoundation                  0x333213ce CFRelease + 290
8   CoreFoundation                  0x333fc430 __CFBasicHashDrain + 256
9   CoreFoundation                  0x333213ce CFRelease + 290
10  ImageIO                         0x34179bb2 releaseInfoPNG + 18
11  ImageIO                         0x34029ae4 ImageProviderReleaseInfoCallback + 32
12  CoreGraphics                    0x3346b1c8 image_provider_finalize + 32
13  CoreFoundation                  0x333213ce CFRelease + 290
14  CoreGraphics                    0x33464f48 image_finalize + 60
15  CoreFoundation                  0x333213ce CFRelease + 290
16  QuartzCore                      0x34fa44ce CA::Layer::State::~State() + 94
17  QuartzCore                      0x34fa7a4e CA::Layer::~Layer() + 290
18  QuartzCore                      0x34fa77ae -[CALayer dealloc] + 138
19  QuartzCore                      0x34f97a70 CA::Layer::free_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 68
20  QuartzCore                      0x34f960a4 CA::Transaction::commit() + 400
21  QuartzCore                      0x34f95eac CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
22  CoreFoundation                  0x333b56ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
23  CoreFoundation                  0x333b39bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
24  CoreFoundation                  0x333b3d12 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
25  CoreFoundation                  0x33326eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
26  CoreFoundation                  0x33326d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
27  GraphicsServices                0x36eea2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
28  UIKit                           0x3523c2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
```

Comment: Please add the rest of the stack trace

Comment: I`ve updated my post. Please check.

Answer (score 7):

This crash occurs when using `NSNotificationCenter`

You registered a notification observer to an object that has been released and didn't removed the observer. So when it tries to call the selector it crashes.

If you are using a ViewController of some kind, you can add

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"Notification" object:nil];
```

to the `viewWillDisappear`

if it is not a ViewController you can use `-(void) dealloc` to unregister the Observer.

Comment: This seems wrong, as per this official Apple answer: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/100012